# Converting machine code snippet to assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

I'm working on an assignment that's asking me to convert some lines of machine code to assembly. Here's an example

0x0000000080001294 : EB01001F

According to some people online, this translates to CMP X0, X1 in assembly.

From what I understand, you're supposed to take the "EB01001F", convert it to binary, and use an opcode table to figure out the rest. When putting it into binary, here's what I get:

11101011000000010000000000011111

The problem is the opcode table in the textbook I have has nothing that matches up with any of this so I'm lost, can someone help me out?

Comment: Which CPU is this for? Those numbers mean different things on different hardware.

Comment: Could be an endianness problem. Try `1F0001EB` instead. I assume this is aarch64.

Comment: looks to be aarch64 and it is right if you assemble that cmp x0,x1 you get 0xEB01001F.  use the arm documentation not a text book it walks you through all the bits in the instruction and/or you can go to the answer and see the bits match

Answer (score 2):

We don't know what table your textbook has. Maybe it has the endianness reversed. [Official arm documentation](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0596/a/DDI_0596_ARM_a64_instruction_set_architecture.pdf) however uses your bit order. You can find the *CMP (shifted register)* instruction which looks like:

```
1110 1011 ss0m mmmm iiii iinn nnn1 1111 (structure from manual)
1110 1011 0000 0001 0000 0000 0001 1111 (your bits)
```

In particular you can see `i=0` (the shift amount), `m=1` (second operand) and `n=0` (first operand) hence it is really `CMP X0, X1` as expected.